# Am I going crazy? UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification not working on simulator or device

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

It's quite a simple issue. In my view controller I'm registering for a 'foreground' notification:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.applicationDidEnterForeground(_:)),
              name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

}

func applicationDidEnterForeground(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("I'm not going crazy")
}
```

### What I'd Expect

After foregrounding the app, the print statement should be executed and printed to the console.

### But...

This never happens. I'm an experienced iOS developer, and I've been trying for an hour or so.

What on earth could I have missed? Is this working for other people? Have tried:

- Different values for *object*, (self, nil,
  `UIApplication.sharedApplication()`)
- Registering for `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` - which ***works fine***
- Restarting Xcode, Simulator
- Running on a device and on the simulator
- Cleaning the build folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an extension on UIViewController was calling

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)`

at will, with no regard to any subclass. Not so helpful, and pretty hard to find since extensions could be somewhere completely unrelated to whatever it is you're working on, and not necessarily even part of the view controller's class heirachy.

If you're writing an extension... keep this is mind!!!

Comment: Then how did registering for a different notification work as stated in your question?

Comment: @rmaddy removing the observer happened shortly after the view initially displayed, after an async operation. I must have been a little lucky when I tried it - i.e. backgrounded the app before the view controller had finished the async call - that's the only explanation I can come up with.